# storing different values given by the computer in an array and then displaying the maximum,minimum,previous values

Tags: javascript

I am creating a reaction timer game in which every time a box comes on the screen on random positions. Then i have to click the box as soon as possible. This makes the box disappear and the computer gives the time in doing so.This process repeats itself. I want to store the times given by the computer in an array and then give the minimum time taken and the previous time. How do i do this?? I have tried using the .push method.This gives the values in different lines and not in a single array. Also it is not giving the minimum time but showing undefined instead.

Comment: where you defined array because its matter

Comment: You should post your approach to the problem and how it is not working, so that people could help you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
  var d = new Date();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
}
```

did you try this approach this method repeat it self and you can wrap this in particukar condition

Comment: Yes I have tried that approach. I think i have to apply a global variable to find the minimum time taken for doing it.

Comment: obviously you are doing with local variable?? it wil reintilize array